# How to place content of uploaded text file on page in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am developing a website in wordpress i want to put a txt file in header for read at time of load

```
     <?php
$myfile = fopen("keyword.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
// Output one character until end-of-file
while(!feof($myfile)) {
   echo fgetc($myfile);
}

fclose($myfile);
?>
```

its giving no file of directory found please help me how to do it n wordpress

Comment: Where is your file located? You obviously have the wrong path.

Comment: where you have located your `keyword.txt` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have `keyword.txt` in your template directory.

```
$myfile = fopen( dirname(__FILE__) . "/keyword.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
```

Comment: How is this assumption any better?

Comment: @rnevius :), I will edit my answer according to the OP INPUT, I know i maybe wrong to assume the location of the file.